# Adding a "back to top button"

Tags: jquery, html, css, shopify

I am doing a project in Shopify, making a website for selling watches basically. I've actually easily maneuvered through several issues here and there, but the problem I have is when I have to add some code in multiple places. In my theme.liquid I've loaded my .css and .js files so I can easily do some stuff in those two and "magic" happens on my site. The problem is that, for example, if I want to add a back to top button, I know the function that I need to write in my .js file, but I do not know where to place the HTML and CSS parts that I need my theme.liquid file. From what I get, in this specific case, both the CSS and the HTML bits I need to write directly in my main file, while defining the actual function in my .js file.

```
<html class="no-js" lang="{{ shop.locale }}">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
  <meta name="theme-color" content="{{ settings.color_button }}">
  <link rel="canonical" href="{{ canonical_url }}">

  {%- if settings.favicon != blank -%}
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="{{ settings.favicon | img_url: '32x32' }}" type="image/png">
  {%- endif -%}

  {%- capture seo_title -%}
    {%- if request.page_type == 'search' and search.performed == true -%}
      {{ 'general.search.heading' | t: count: search.results_count }}: {{ 'general.search.results_with_count' | t: terms: search.terms, count: search.results_count }}
    {%- else -%}
      {{ page_title }}
    {%- endif -%}
    {%- if current_tags -%}
      {%- assign meta_tags = current_tags | join: ', ' -%} &ndash; {{ 'general.meta.tags' | t: tags: meta_tags -}}
    {%- endif -%}
    {%- if current_page != 1 -%}
      &ndash; {{ 'general.meta.page' | t: page: current_page }}
    {%- endif -%}
    {%- assign escaped_page_title = page_title | escape -%}
    {%- unless escaped_page_title contains shop.name -%}
      &ndash; {{ shop.name }}
    {%- endunless -%}
  {%- endcapture -%}
  <title>{{ seo_title | strip }}</title>

  {%- if page_description -%}
    <meta name="description" content="{{ page_description | escape }}">
  {%- endif -%}

  {% include 'social-meta-tags' %}

  {{ 'theme.scss.css' | asset_url | stylesheet_tag }}

  <script>
    var theme = {
      breakpoints: {
        medium: 750,
        large: 990,
        widescreen: 1400
      },
      strings: {
        addToCart: {{ 'products.product.add_to_cart' | t | json }},
        soldOut: {{ 'products.product.sold_out' | t | json }},
        unavailable: {{ 'products.product.unavailable' | t | json }},
        regularPrice: {{ 'products.product.regular_price' | t | json }},
        salePrice: {{
          'products.product.sale_price' | t | json }},
        sale: {{ 'products.product.on_sale' | t | json }},
        showMore: {{ 'general.filters.show_more' | t | json }},
        showLess: {{ 'general.filters.show_less' | t | json }},
        addressError: {{ 'sections.map.address_error' | t | json }},
        addressNoResults: {{ 'sections.map.address_no_results' | t | json }},
        addressQueryLimit: {{ 'sections.map.address_query_limit_html' | t | json }},
        authError: {{ 'sections.map.auth_error_html' | t | json }},
        newWindow: {{ 'general.accessibility.link_messages.new_window' | t | json }},
        external: {{ 'general.accessibility.link_messages.external' | t | json }},
        newWindowExternal: {{ 'general.accessibility.link_messages.new_window_and_external' | t | json }},
        removeLabel: {{ 'cart.label.remove' | t: product: '[product]' | json }},
        update: {{ 'cart.label.update' | t | json }},
        quantity: {{ 'cart.label.quantity' | t | json }},
        discountedTotal: {{ 'cart.label.discounted_total' | t | json }},
        regularTotal: {{ 'cart.label.regular_total' | t | json }},
        priceColumn: {{ 'cart.label.price_column' | t | json }},
        quantityMinimumMessage: {{ 'products.product.quantity_minimum_message' | t | json }},
        cartError: {{ 'cart.general.cart_error' | t | json }},
        removedItemMessage: {{ 'cart.general.removed_item_html' | t: quantity: '[quantity]', link: '[link]' | json }},
        unitPrice: {{ 'products.product.unit_price_label' | t | json }},
        unitPriceSeparator: {{ 'general.accessibility.unit_price_separator' | t | json }},
        oneCartCount: {{ 'cart.popup.cart_count' | t: count: 1 | json }},
        otherCartCount: {{ 'cart.popup.cart_count' | t: count: '[count]' | json }},
        quantityLabel: {{ 'cart.popup.quantity_label' | t: quantity_count: '[count]' | json }}
      },
      moneyFormat: {{ shop.money_format | json }},
      moneyFormatWithCurrency: {{ shop.money_with_currency_format | json }}
    }

    document.documentElement.className = document.documentElement.className.replace('no-js', 'js');
  </script>


  {%- if request.page_type contains 'customers/' -%}
    <script src="{{ 'shopify_common.js' | shopify_asset_url }}" defer="defer"></script>
  {%- endif -%}

  <script src="{{ 'lazysizes.js' | asset_url }}" async="async"></script>
  <script src="{{ 'vendor.js' | asset_url }}" defer="defer"></script>
  <script src="{{ 'theme.js' | asset_url }}" defer="defer"></script>

  {{ content_for_header }} 






  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  {{'johndoe.css' | asset_url | stylesheet_tag }}

<script>
window.mlvedaShopCurrency = "{{ shop.currency }}";
window.shopCurrency = "{{ shop.currency }}";
window.supported_currencies = "{{ settings.mlvedaACS_supportedCurrencies }}";
</script></head>

<body class="template-{{ request.page_type | handle }}">

  <a class="in-page-link visually-hidden skip-link" href="#MainContent">{{ 'general.accessibility.skip_to_content' | t }}</a>

  <div id="SearchDrawer" class="search-bar drawer drawer--top" role="dialog" aria-modal="true" aria-label="{{ 'general.search.placeholder' | t }}">
    <div class="search-bar__table">
      <div class="search-bar__table-cell search-bar__form-wrapper">
        <form class="search search-bar__form" action="{{ routes.search_url }}" method="get" role="search">
          <input class="search__input search-bar__input" type="search" name="q" value="{{ search.terms | escape }}" placeholder="{{ 'general.search.placeholder' | t }}" aria-label="{{ 'general.search.placeholder' | t }}">
          <button class="search-bar__submit search__submit btn--link" type="submit">
            {% include 'icon-search' %}
            <span class="icon__fallback-text">{{ 'general.search.submit' | t }}</span>
          </button>
        </form>
      </div>
      <div class="search-bar__table-cell text-right">
        <button type="button" class="btn--link search-bar__close js-drawer-close">
          {% include 'icon-close' %}
          <span class="icon__fallback-text">{{ 'general.search.close' | t }}</span>
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  {%- if settings.enable_ajax -%}
    {% include 'cart-popup' %}
  {%- endif -%}

  {% section 'header' %}

  <div class="page-container" id="PageContainer">

    <main class="main-content js-focus-hidden" id="MainContent" role="main" tabindex="-1">
      {{ content_for_layout }}
    </main>

    {% section 'footer' %}

    <div id="slideshow-info" class="visually-hidden" aria-hidden="true">
      {{- 'sections.slideshow.navigation_instructions' | t -}}
    </div>

  </div>

  <ul hidden>
    <li id="a11y-refresh-page-message">{{ 'general.accessibility.refresh_page' | t }}</li>
    <li id="a11y-selection-message">{{ 'general.accessibility.selection_help' | t }}</li>
  </ul>
  {{'johndoe.js' | asset_url | script_tag}}

{% include 'mlveda-currencies-switcher' %}{% include 'mlveda-currencies' %}{% include 'mlveda-flag' %}{% include 'mlveda-currencies-style' %}
{% include 'swymSnippet' %}


{% include 'gtranslate', float: 'yes' %}
</body>
</html>
```

I know it's kind of annoying to surf through that code, but can anyone assist me in exaplining where I need to put the CSS and HTML parts so that my button does appear on my web-site?

Comment: [This is what I see](https://help.shopify.com/en/themes/customization/store/add-back-to-top-button) from a quick google search with your title. It is exactly what you are looking for and is from the shopify help center.

Comment: This can have many different methods to accomplish the same thing. You can do it with HTML alone. You can add Styling. You can also do it with JavaScript. Do you have a preference? What have you tried?

Comment: The purpose of this project is to heavily use JavaScript and jquerry. I can easily add an addon or plugin to the page and don't even have to use HTML at all. But that is not the purpose.

Comment: If you read the provided link you will see that this is a **built in** functionality and does not require any plugin or additional script to be built Or you are going to reinvent the wheel? Then you should know already what you are doing

Comment: @LelioFaieta I just said that the purpose of the project is to create these things in js and jquerry, and your answer is basically why bother if I can just add them without any effort? Because that's the point of what I have to do!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understood your question. If your need a simple button to get back to the top of your page, then you easily place a link somewhere at the bottom of your HTML code.

```
<a href="#top">back to top</a>
```

Maybe you need to create an anker with the ID "top", but I think there is a kind of magic in most browsers (I'm not the frontend guy).

Now you can use CSS to style the link as button.

Comment: Well, although I know how to define functions with JS, I haven't used HTML and CSS much. And as such, even though I know how I can make a function for a button to do it, I simply did not know where exactly in my code I can place that line you just entered so that the certain button appears on my page, as most of the things that are on my page are pre-made from the template I used.

Comment: You do not need JavaScript for that. The code for the link you add for example before "</body></html>" and the CSS in your *.sass (?) file.